# fastest way to find if all the elements of an array are distinct?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am looking for a faster way to find whether an array of elements contains distinct elements only. The worst thing to do is to take each element and compare it to every other element in the array. Next best would be to sort the list and then compare, which still does not improves this much. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Depends on the language and its built in classes.  But I think the best you can do is O(N) time.

Comment: What kind of elements are in your array? If they are numbers, you might use an array and set/test bits to see if the same number was already set before.

Comment: Fun fact: if you know the number of elements is greater than the range of elements you know you have a collision.

Comment: Sorting does not improve it much? Let's see. Comparing each element against every other element is O(n^2), and sorting then comparing is O(n log n). When n==1 million, you'll find the sort and compare to be *much* faster.

Comment: Isn't the worst case O(n^2 log n) which is significantly better than O(n^2)?  Because the elements are localised you only need to step through a sorted array once to compare the value of the previous element with the current one.  If they are the same then you don't have a distinct element.

Comment: I am sorry for mentioning that sorting will be no better. I was hoping for something better than sorting.

Answer (score 25):

**Brute-force:**

Brute-force (checking every element with every other element) takes `O(n2)`.

**Sorting:**

Sorting takes `O(n log n)`, which is generally considered to be a fairly decent running time.

Sorting has the advantage above the below (hash table) approach in that it can be done in-place (`O(1)` extra space), where-as the below takes `O(n)` extra space.

**Hash table:**

An alternative is to use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

For each item:

- Check if that item exists in the hash table (if it does, all items are not distinct) and
- Insert that item into the hash table

Since insert and contains queries run in expected `O(1)` on a hash table, the overall running time would be expected `O(n)`, and, as mentioned above, `O(n)` extra space.

**Bit array:**

Another alternative, if the elements are all integers in some given range, is to have a [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) with size equal to the range of integers.

Similarly to what was done for the hash table approach, for each element, you'd check whether the applicable bit is set, and then set it.

This takes `O(m + n)` time and `O(m)` extra space where `m` is the range of integers and `n` is the size of the array (unless you consider allocating the array to be free, in which case it just takes `O(n)` time).

Comment: Maybe you want to note that sorting is O(n log n) while the naive compare-all-pairs algorithm is O(n^2) which is actually a *lot* worse. Or maybe you don't :)

Comment: Good answer. Also should note that the hash table requires O(n) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks. Added a note for that.

Comment: @rici Expanded on my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Red and Black tree where elements as keys and number of occurrences are value. You can then navigate the tree. Time and space complexity is O(n) where n is the number of elements. Key benefits using a red and black tree include consistent performance and simple memory management - excellent choice for a distributed environement. Perspectives welcome.

Comment: I had found this way but didn't had the chance to update here. Given that I only want a boolean true/false for distinct/non-distinct, I can even stop constructing the tree when I encounter a value greater than one.

Comment: time complexity is *not* O(n)! red black tree insertion is lg n, so time complexity is n lg n just to create the tree

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution (interesting only from theoretic point of view):

I think you can adapt the [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm. In short, this algorithm runs in the same way as Quick sort, but it only splits the array in two groups, according to some chosen pivot (less and more than the pivot, respectively), thus the sorting is omitted. It's average case performance is O(n).

My idea is to look for elements equal to the chosen pivot on each step. In this way, whenever there are more than two elements, we will compare the pivot to each element. If we have found a duplicate, we have the answer. Otherwise we split the problem in two similar ones, but with smaller size and run the algorithm on them.

*Disclaimer*: The worst case performance of Quickselect is O(n^2). Therefore, using a hash table is way more *time* efficient.

However, as Quickselect is an [in-place algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), it requires only constant memory overhead as opposed to linear additional memory for a hash table (not that it matters nowadays).

Comment: You'll have to explain how repetitively invoking Quickselect is going to be faster than just doing a Quicksort. In particular you say, "look for elements equal to the chosen pivot on each step." What is "each step?"

Comment: We will invoke a Quickselect-like algo (it won't have the K parameter, used by Quickselect) only once. It will be faster than Quicksort, because it won't actually sort the elements (in this way it is O(n)). By "each step" I mean on every time we are in the body of the recursive function and we are choosing a pivot.

Comment: But you have to do that for every item in the list, making the algorithm O(n^2). You can optimize that to O(n log n) by selecting subsets after the first pivot, but doing so requires extra memory and overhead that will make it slower than Quicksort. Unless I've completely misunderstood your approach, in which case perhaps you should post an implementation. Because if you can do this in O(n) with no extra space, then you've proven much of computer science theory wrong.

Comment: You are right. The advantage of Quickselect is that it continues recursively with only one of the groups. In my idea, I would have to call the procedure on *both* groups. Therefore, it loses the advantage of Quickselect. As you said, it can be implemented in O(n log n), but this does not add any value to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is O(1) space complexity approach. The idea is that we will just keep the array with unique elements in the beginning of itself.
The time complexity is O(n*log(n)) since we want to avoid space usage and so we can use python's in-place sort method for list.
It may feel like C, but worked for me

```
    a.sort()
    i = 0
    k = 0
    while i < len(a) - 1:
        if a[i] == a[i+1]:
            j = i
            while j < len(a) - 1 and a[j] == a[j+1]:
                j += 1
            if j < len(a) - 1:
                a[k+1] = a[j+1]
                i = j + 1
                k += 1
            else:
                pass
        else:
            i += 1
            k += 1
    a = a[:k+1]
```