# Is there an algorithm that checks whether a container contains only distinct elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hello I want to find some algorithm that checks whether a container contains all distinct elements.

Here is what I've tried:

```
template <typename It>
bool hasAllDistinctElems(It first, It last){
    for(auto i = first; i != last; ++i)
        for(auto j = i; ++j != last; )
            if(*i == *j )
                return false;
    return true;
}


int main(){

    std::vector<int> vi{5, 7, 3, 8, 2, 7, 5};
    std::deque<int> di{1, 5, 7, 2, 3, 8, 6};
    std::cout << hasAllDistinctElems( vi.cbegin(), vi.cend() ) << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << hasAllDistinctElems( di.cbegin(), di.cend() ) << '\n'; // 1
}
```

It works just fine but I've found another method:

- copy all the elements of the first container into a container that guarantees the uniqueness of its elements like the STL associative containers like `std::set`, `std::map`.
- Compare the sizes of the containers so if the sizes are equal it means all the elements from the first one has been copied to the set which means they are all unique otherwise they are not unique thus not all of them have been copied into the set:

  ```
  #include <unordered_set>
  #include <deque>
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>

  int main(){

      std::vector<int> vi{5, 7, 3, 8, 2, 7, 5};
      std::deque<int> di{1, 5, 7, 2, 3, 8, 6};

      std::unordered_set<int> usi(vi.cbegin(), vi.cend());
      std::unordered_set<int> usi2(di.cbegin(), di.cend());

      std::cout << std::boolalpha;
      std::cout << "vi's all distinct? " << (vi.size() == usi.size()) << '\n'; // false
      std::cout << "di's all distinct? " << (di.size() == usi2.size()) << '\n'; // true

  }
  ```
- Both work fine but I'd like to know which one should I use? Is there an algorithm that does that?? or another workaround? Thank you!

Comment: If the data is sorted, `std::unique` is an option.

Comment: @Itachi Uchiwa Not all containers have the member function at.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Do you mean compare the returned iterator from `std::unique` and compare it against the off-the-end iterator of the container so if they are equal, it means all the elements are distinct otherwise they are not? 

* If so, `std::unique` removes elements by moving them to the second part of the container.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Yeah, it would be destructive if not all elements are unique.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: yes I know, like `std::list` and built-in arrays but the code only for practice. On the other hand, not all the containers do support the subscript operator and there are some causes it insert elements that don't exist like the subscript operator on `std::map`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Also `std::unique` requires that the elements must be sorted before it is called: 


    `std::vector<int> v{2, 5, 2, 7, 2, 6};
    if(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()) == v.end() )
        std::cout << "v cnotains all distinct values\n";
    else
        std::cout << "v doesn't cnotain all distinct values\n";`

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa You could use iterators instead of the function.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa I did say *If the data is sorted*

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Ah thanks. I did miss that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you

Comment: Are the elements always integers? The unordered_set solution is likely the simplest you'll find. Several language-agnostic solutions are also [presented in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180902/fastest-way-to-find-if-all-the-elements-of-an-array-are-distinct)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I've implemented it using iterators and it works just fine:

`template <typename It>
bool hasAllDistinctElems(It first, It last){
    for(auto i = first; i != last; ++i)
        for(auto j = i; ++j != last; )
            if(*i == *j )
                return false;
    return true;
}`. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Then if the sequence is ordered then what do you think about the algorithm `std::adjacent_find`? Which search for any pair of equal elements  in the sequence without modifying it.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa That is a good use of the algorithm.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you for the advice.

Comment: *"which one should I use?"* -- that depends on your requirements. For example, if space is at a premium, then your second proposal is out because it requires additional space. On the other hand, if you can afford the space, your second proposal is faster. So we cannot tell you which to use; we can only tell you the pros and cons of each. See the "Constructive subjective questions" part of the [help/dont-ask] for some ideas for improving your question.

Comment: @JaMiT: Thank you.